# How to find which function or event is getting triggered on change of value on the select box in the below code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, servicenow

```
<p>${Agenda Items Widget}</p>
<div id="pending-agenda-item-widget" class="panel panel-default" role="region" tabindex="0" aria-label="${Agenda Items Widget}" accessibility="{{meeting.accessible}}">
  <div class="panel-heading heading widget-heading heading-border" ng-class="{'heading-inactive': meeting.viewingCurrent()}">
      <div class="flex">
        <label for="cab-pending-agenda-filter" class="sr-only">${Agenda list filter}</label>
        <select id="cab-pending-agenda-filter" class="sn-select-basic expand" ng-model="selectedItem" ng-init="selectedItem = CAB.PENDING" ng-disabled="page.loading" tabindex="0">
          
            <option value="{{::CAB.PENDING}}">{{::c.data.i18n.filter[CAB.PENDING]}}</option>
            <option value="{{::CAB.ALL}}">{{::c.data.i18n.filter[CAB.ALL]}}</option>
            <option value="{{::CAB.MINE}}">{{::c.data.i18n.filter[CAB.MINE]}}</option>
            <option value="{{::CAB.APPROVED}}">{{::c.data.i18n.filter[CAB.APPROVED]}}</option>
            <option value="{{::CAB.COMPLETE}}">{{::c.data.i18n.filter[CAB.COMPLETE]}}</option>
        </select>
```

i want to know which function is getting triggered on change of value on the select box "cab-pending-agenda-filter" and pass adding value to the same function

Comment: as there is no explicit ng-change method on the element, you'll have to scour your code either for a directive that extends the `select` element or maybe some non-angular jquery code that puts a listener on `#cab-pending-agenda-filter`

Answer (score 0):

Just add an onchange directive to your select element:

```
<label for="cab-pending-agenda-filter" class="sr-only">${Agenda list filter}</label>
<select 
id="cab-pending-agenda-filter" 
class="sn-select-basic expand" 
ng-model="selectedItem" 
   ng-change="selectChanged(selectedItem)"
ng-init="selectedItem = CAB.PENDING" 
ng-disabled="page.loading" 
tabindex="0">
          
            <option value="{{::CAB.PENDING}}">{{::c.data.i18n.filter[CAB.PENDING]}}</option>
            <option value="{{::CAB.ALL}}">{{::c.data.i18n.filter[CAB.ALL]}}</option>
            <option value="{{::CAB.MINE}}">{{::c.data.i18n.filter[CAB.MINE]}}</option>
            <option value="{{::CAB.APPROVED}}">{{::c.data.i18n.filter[CAB.APPROVED]}}</option>
            <option value="{{::CAB.COMPLETE}}">{{::c.data.i18n.filter[CAB.COMPLETE]}}</option>
        </select>
```

then define the assigned method in the $scope of the controller that contains the select box:

```
$scope.selectChanged =  function(value) {
   // ... do stuff here when the select value is changed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you just want to see if any event is assigned to the element you can:

1. open chrome devtools
2. inspect the 'select' element and make sure it is selected in the 'Elements' tab of devtools
3. open the console drawer (pressing Esc) if not open already
4. in the console input type: console.log($0.onchange)

This will output the contents of any function if assigned previously to the element onchange event.